# JavaScript function prototype calling parent from child

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, namespaces, prototype

I have a stupid reference problem

I declared a namespace variable called MYAPP

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || function() {

     this.name = 'My Application';
     this.someImportantID = 123;

};
```

And then I wanted to sperate my code in namespaces/functions and so I did

```
MYAPP.prototype.homepage = function() {
    urls: {
        linkOne: '/link/to/some/page/',
        linkTwo: '/link/to/some/page/'
     },
   doSomething: function() {

        // ajax call 
           $getting = $.get(this.urls.linkOne) 
        // and so on .....

        // how can I acces someImportantID ??

     }
}
```

then i use it like this

```
app = new MYAPP();
app.homepage.doSomething();
```

but how can I access **someImportantID** within the function **doSomething()**

Comment: Is there any reason you're using MYAPP as a constructor instead of just doing `var MYAPP = MYAPP || {...}`?

Comment: Is there any difference in performance?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this .homepage stuff.  Why are you doing that anyway?

This is something of a constructor pattern.  Declare your constructor:

```
var MYAPP = function(URLCollection) {

     this._name = 'My Application';
     this._someImportantID = 123;
     this._URLCollection = URLCollection;

}
```

Then declare the instance methods:

```
MYAPP.prototype = {

   doSomething: function() {

        // ajax call 
           $getting = $.get(this._URLCollection.linkOne);

        // and so on .....

        // how can I acces someImportantID ??

     }
}
```

Then declare your instance passing in your collection of links:

```
var lCollection = { linkOne: 'URL', linkTwo: 'URL' };
var myHomePage = new MYAPP(lCollection);
```

You can access doSomething from the instance:

```
myHomePage.doSomething();
```

You can get to some important ID from the instance also:

```
myHomePage._someImportantId;
```

Or from within the instance, by:

```
this._someImportantId;
```

This is rough - it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes I know, but I have many other pages like homepage. And Every page has its own (different) functions, I want to seperate them in different files, otherwise its a very long file

Comment: I think what I and a few others are thrown by is your use of a constructor.  Why follow the constructor pattern when all you really need are separate modules?  I recommend that you search for Addy Osmani's book 'Javascript Design Patterns' and give it a read.  You can find a copy here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: yes thanks for the link, I have changed the myapp function to an object, then I have created modules like this, myapp.homepage.doSomething(), myapp.otherpage.doSomething() , this is what I wanted, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple MyApp instances then you can do the following:

```
//IIFE creating it's own scope, HomePage constructor
// is no longer globally available
;(function(){
  var HomePage = function(urls,app){
    this.urls=urls;
    this.app=app;
  }
  HomePage.prototype.doSomething=function(){
    console.log('urls:',this.urls,'app:',this.app);
  }
  //assuming window is the global   
  window.MyApp = function(urls){
    this.name='app name';
    this.homePage=new HomePage(urls,this);
  }
}());
var app = new MyApp(['url one','url two']);
app.homePage.doSomething();
```

If you only have one app and that app only has one homePage object you can do it the following way as well:

```
var app = {
  name:'app name'
  ,homePage:{
    urls:['url one','url two']
    ,doSomething:function(){
      console.log('urls:',this.urls,'app:',app);
      //or
      console.log('urls:',app.homePage.urls,'app:',app);
    }
  }
}

app.homePage.doSomething();
```

More on constructor functions, prototype and the value of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

Comment: I see how you pass this to the homepage function but how can I disclose Homepage within myapp scope, it doesnt have to be a global variable

Comment: There is just one global MYAPP variable

Comment: @webmaster I asked if there are more then one instances, not if you have only one constructor function. There is a difference (see link at the end of the answer). I used different capitalization because all caps is the convention for constants. I have edited my answer to have the Homepage constructor only available in the MyApp constructor.

Comment: I meant one instance ;)

Comment: @webmaster In that case there is no need to use a constructor function and declare both app and homePage as an object literal as done in the second block of code.